# How do you measure the performance metrics of a program?

Tags: performance

I am doing an investigation into two different code languages to compare them and see how they perform differently to each other. I understand the basic differences between things like interpreted languages and static languages but I want to generate numbers by which I can express those differences. Does anyone know what metrics I should be looking at specifically and do I simply add extra code to my programs to give information like runtime or are there tools out there that can do a better job?

Comment: A naive approach would be 1) decide an an algorithm (e.g. [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sieve-of-eratosthenes/)), 2) code the algorithm in one or more languages, 3) Run your program(s) and time the results

Comment: @FoggyDay Yes that is what I have done, I have tried to keep as the programs as similar as possible literally  just translating them across. Do you think runtime is the most important metric?

Comment: Do you want to compare two specific codes or two specific programming languages? Comparing programming languages is generally like comparing oranges and apples. Even on a specific well-defined metric (and "performance" is not well-defined). Can you clarify what you exactly want or/and give an example?

Comment: @Jérôme Richard I want to demonstrate the differences of running a program in one language to another. I wan't to specifically compare python to a new language called Nim which is based on python but is static as opposed to interpreted.

Comment: Q: Do you think runtime is the most important metric?  A: No, but I definitely think "chocolate" is the best flavor.  The question is *ABSURD*.  There's an almost *infinite* #/criteria for choosing a language.  Even a single criteria (e.g. "timing") can be complicated.  For example, do you mean "latency" - time to finish a fixed task, or "throughput" - the #/tasks in fixed time?  Or something else entirely?  There's no "One True Answer"; there's no "simple metric" you can use to determine "Good" or "Bad".

Comment: @FoggyDay I'm not asking for anything definitive that says good or bad all languages have their niche uses that make them good in some areas and bad in others but in general what aspects of a program are important in a system usage sense.